# Python Autosys automation

Tags: autosys

I have set of scripts. I have automated it locally to run those scripts using Python. As I am new tp Python and doesn't know Autosys as well. My requirement is to automate these sets of scripts from a VM so that these jobs run as a batch job on Autosys daily. How to achieve it?

Comment: Setup Autosys client on the remote host and then create an instance and define job under this instance to run on the remote host.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide an example as I am new to Autosys and Python?

Comment: sorry mate, i have not worked on the setup of these services (the dedicated middleware team does it) ... my experience is in using these services.

Comment: btw do you have autosys already installed ?
i can help with scheduling those jobs.

Comment: Autosys is already installed. I want to write a Python program to trigger the jobs on Autosys.

Comment: alright... so tell me more about the 1. os.. windows / unix ? 2. What does python script does ? because the set of scripts can be triggered through scheduled jobs directly from autosys. be it time or condition dependent

Answer (score 0):

Man you need to describe at which stage you are at.

Consider an ideal situation, on linux machine
A script(python/shell/perl) is expected to run based on condition like a specific time or after success of a previous script. In Autosys, you can define jobs with condition. Once the condition is true it would trigger the command specified.

Consider, you wish to execute a python script /absolute_path/hello.py everyday at 08:00 hours. Here, i would define my Autosys job using a JIL file as following:

```
insert_job: HELLO_WORLD JOB                     # Job Name
job_type: CMD                                   # A command job
command: python /absolute_path/hello.py         # Execute the python script
owner: xyz                                      # User through which the script would execute
machine: localhost                              # Hostname / DNS name of the node
date_conditions: 1                              # Boolean to follow time condition or not
days_of_week: all                               # Run everyday
start_times: "08:00"                            # Time of run
```